# How to calculate mean value of two list for each row

Tags: r

I have two lists as below:

```
l1 <- list(a=1, b=2, c=3)
l2 <- list(a=4, b=5, c=6)
```

I want to calculate the mean value of the two lists for each row and assign the result to a new list. Like below:

```
l3 <- mean(l1, l2)
```

How can I achieve this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Map`

```
Map(function(x,y) mean(c(x,y)), l1, l2)
```

---

Or with `map2` from `purrr`

```
purrr::map2(l1, l2, ~ mean(c(.x, .y)))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(l1, l2) %>% 
      summarise_all(mean) %>%
      unlist() %>%
      relist(., skeleton = l1)
```

---

Or another option is

```
relist((unlist(l1) + unlist(l2))/2, skeleton= l1)
```

NOTE: All the solutions return a `list` as the OP mentioned in the post

Answer (score 4):

Using:

```
colMeans(do.call(rbind.data.frame, list(l1,l2)))
```

gives:

```
  a   b   c 
2.5 3.5 4.5
```

Answer (score 2):

```
apply(cbind(do.call(rbind,l1),do.call(rbind,l2)),1, mean)
```